sed command OR operator not working in a group
I'm running on MacOS.
I have a file which contains these lines:
This is ('apple').
This is ('orange').
This is ('banana').

When I search for an apple using sed it works:
cat file.txt | sed -n "/(\('apple'\)/p"

But when I try to search for an apple or an orange, it does not work and returns nothing:
cat file.txt | sed -n "/(\('apple'|'orange'\)/p"

What should be the correct sed regex to use or operator inside a group capture??
Thank you.

I finally make it work by adding the -E flag.
cat file.txt | sed -nE "/\('(apple|orange)/p"


sed accepts BRE regex patterns by default, where (, ) and | have to be preceded by \ to be used as special characters for grouping and alternation:
sed -n "/(\('apple'\|'orange'\))/p" file.txt


not working, thanks btw.

that link is for GNU-specific documentation. The standard doesn't require that \| enables ERE functionality in BREs - https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9799919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_02
